# Google Custom Search query

Tags: javascript, search, google-api, search-engine, google-custom-search

I'm trying to build a simple webpage where I want to search some query on google and either on button click or enter it writes the query on console (I want to do more with it but this is just a simple test case).

I'm new to web programming and I'm having trouble making this. The problem is that it is not writing the query, and it gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on " $('input.gsc-input') ".

I've tried adapting diverse solutions I've seen around the internet and this is my final code:

```
<script>
function gcseCallback() {
    if (document.readyState != 'complete')
    return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
    google.search.cse.element.render({gname:'gsearch', div:'results',tag:'search', attributes:{linkTarget:''}});
   var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
   $('input.gsc-input').keypress(function(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){  
            console.log('enter pressed');
            console.log(element.getInputQuery());
         }
  });
  $('input.gsc-search-button').on('click', function(e){
     console.log('clicked');
     console.log(element.getInputQuery());
  });

 };

  window.__gcse = {
      parsetags: 'explicit',
      callback: gcseCallback
  };



 (function() {
  var cx = '012011985098456266711:mn0nz0gkkxs';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Please post where and how you load jQuery. There is something wrong I guess.

Comment: @luuksen After reading your comment I did realise I was doing it wrong, I've changed it to '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>' right in the beginning of the code. Now, the on click works but on enter there's still no results